# funciones con Listas e Input con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Soy Nuevo y también entusiasta en la programación con Python, en este momento me encuentro buscando una guía para solucionar un inconveniente con una Lista para que me sume y me multiplique los datos ingresados a una lista desde una función Sumarizar y otra función Multiplicar, cuando lo ejecuto solo me muestra el primer campo de la lista pero no la suma ni la multiplicación. Adjunto el código.

```
def sumarizar (lista):
suma = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    suma += lista[i]
    return suma

def multiplicar (lista):
multiplicador = 1
for i in range(len(lista)):
    multiplicador *= lista[i]
    return multiplicador

seleccion = int(input('Presiona 1 Para sumar ó 2 para Multiplicar: '))

if seleccion == 1:
listaValores = [int(input('Ingresa los valores a Sumar: '))
    for i in range(int(input('Ingresa Cuantos valores va sumar: ')))
]
print (sumarizar(listaValores))

if seleccion == 2:
listaValor = [int(input('Ingresa los valores a multiplicar: '))
    for i in range(int(input('Ingresa Cuantos valores va multiplicar: ')))
]
print (multiplicar(listaValor))
```

Agradezco mucho el aporte que me puedan dar, y me encuentro aquí solicitando ayuda para continuar creeciendo y aprendiendo en la programación. Saludos!

Comment: eso es por que el `for` solo se ejecuta una vez. Se hace la primera iteración y luego se  retorna el valor, y finaliza todo

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el inconveniente era un problema de indentanción en el return por esta razón solo mostraba el primer valor de la lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta a mi propia pregunta. pero agregare la respuesta.

```py
def sumarizar (lista):
    suma = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        suma += lista[i]
    return suma

def multiplicar (lista):
    multiplicador = 1
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        multiplicador *= lista[i]
    return multiplicador

    seleccion = int(input('Presiona 1 Para sumar ó 2 para Multiplicar: '))

if seleccion == 1:
    listaValores = [int(input('Ingresa los valores a Sumar: '))
        for i in range(int(input('Ingresa Cuantos valores va sumar: ')))
    ]
    print (sumarizar(listaValores)) 
    
if seleccion == 2:
    listaValores = [int(input('Ingresa los valores a multiplicar: '))
        for i in range(int(input('Ingresa Cuantos valores va multiplicar: ')))
    ]
    
    print (multiplicar(listaValores))
```

era un tema de indentación, y me estoy dando cuenta de lo sensible es Python con este aspecto. gracias por las vistas y por sus comentarios.